# how to debug cakephp 3.5 cache basedir issue?

Tags: php, caching, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have an app in cakephp 3 which started to report `open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s)` a few weeks ago. I tried to debug it but I wasn't successful in finding the reason why. The app worked okay for like 2.5 years and it just started to appear now but without any changes of code parts which use caching or changing config. In config I have "path" set correctly for every cache mode. And it also is not from consistent url/method. It appears randomly in like less than 1% of calls now. It was more often the first week or so. Is there any way how to debug this and find the reason? Do you know any possible reason for this behavior? I have tried everything I could think of but without success.

Example of config:

```
'hour' => [
            'className' => 'File',
            'path' => CACHE,
            'serialize' => true,
            'duration' => '+1 hour',
            'url' => env('CACHE_DEFAULT_URL', null),
        ],
```

debug trace of one example:

```
Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler::handleError() - CORE/src/Error/BaseErrorHandler.php, line 153
is_dir - [internal], line ??
Cake\Cache\Engine\FileEngine::_clearDirectory() - CORE/src/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php, line 303
Cake\Cache\Engine\FileEngine::clear() - CORE/src/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php, line 284
Cake\Cache\Engine\FileEngine::gc() - CORE/src/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php, line 116
Cake\Cache\CacheRegistry::_create() - CORE/src/Cache/CacheRegistry.php, line 98
Cake\Core\ObjectRegistry::load() - CORE/src/Core/ObjectRegistry.php, line 96
DebugKit\Cache\Engine\DebugEngine::init() - ROOT/vendor/cakephp/debug_kit/src/Cache/Engine/DebugEngine.php, line 79
Cake\Cache\CacheRegistry::_create() - CORE/src/Cache/CacheRegistry.php, line 90
Cake\Core\ObjectRegistry::load() - CORE/src/Core/ObjectRegistry.php, line 96
Cake\Cache\Cache::_buildEngine() - CORE/src/Cache/Cache.php, line 170
Cake\Cache\Cache::engine() - CORE/src/Cache/Cache.php, line 228
Cake\Cache\Cache::read() - CORE/src/Cache/Cache.php, line 356
App\Controller\AppController::beforeRender() - APP/Controller/AppController.php, line 169
Cake\Event\EventManager::_callListener() - CORE/src/Event/EventManager.php, line 416
Cake\Event\EventManager::dispatch() - CORE/src/Event/EventManager.php, line 393
Cake\Controller\Controller::dispatchEvent() - CORE/src/Event/EventDispatcherTrait.php, line 110
Cake\Controller\Controller::render() - CORE/src/Controller/Controller.php, line 610
Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/src/Http/ActionDispatcher.php, line 125
Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/src/Http/ActionDispatcher.php, line 93
Cake\Http\BaseApplication::__invoke() - CORE/src/Http/BaseApplication.php, line 108
Cake\Http\Runner::__invoke() - CORE/src/Http/Runner.php, line 65
Cake\Http\Middleware\EncryptedCookieMiddleware::__invoke() - CORE/src/Http/Middleware/EncryptedCookieMiddleware.php, line 89
Cake\Http\Runner::__invoke() - CORE/src/Http/Runner.php, line 65
Cake\Http\Middleware\CsrfProtectionMiddleware::__invoke() - CORE/src/Http/Middleware/CsrfProtectionMiddleware.php, line 106
App\Application::App\{closure}() - APP/Application.php, line 93
Cake\Http\Runner::__invoke() - CORE/src/Http/Runner.php, line 65
Cake\Http\Middleware\SecurityHeadersMiddleware::__invoke() - CORE/src/Http/Middleware/SecurityHeadersMiddleware.php, line 176
Cake\Http\Runner::__invoke() - CORE/src/Http/Runner.php, line 65
Cake\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware::__invoke() - CORE/src/Routing/Middleware/RoutingMiddleware.php, line 104
Cake\Http\Runner::__invoke() - CORE/src/Http/Runner.php, line 65
Cake\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware::__invoke() - CORE/src/Routing/Middleware/AssetMiddleware.php, line 88
Cake\Http\Runner::__invoke() - CORE/src/Http/Runner.php, line 65
Cake\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware::__invoke() - CORE/src/Error/Middleware/ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php, line 98
Cake\Http\Runner::__invoke() - CORE/src/Http/Runner.php, line 65
Cake\Http\Middleware\EncryptedCookieMiddleware::__invoke() - CORE/src/Http/Middleware/EncryptedCookieMiddleware.php, line 89
Cake\Http\Runner::__invoke() - CORE/src/Http/Runner.php, line 65
DebugKit\Middleware\DebugKitMiddleware::__invoke() - ROOT/vendor/cakephp/debug_kit/src/Middleware/DebugKitMiddleware.php, line 52
Cake\Http\Runner::__invoke() - CORE/src/Http/Runner.php, line 65
Cake\Http\Runner::run() - CORE/src/Http/Runner.php, line 51
Cake\Http\Server::run() - CORE/src/Http/Server.php, line 81
[main] - ROOT/webroot/index.php, line 40
```

I would be grateful for any hint.

Comment: In which relation is `/` to what `CACHE` points to? Is it possibly the immediate parent directory? And has your `open_basedir` option, or perhaps your PHP version been changed latetly?

Comment: No unfortunately nor PHP version nor open_basedir settings was changed as far as I know or server master claims. And `/` is 4 levels up from `CACHE`. I'm really stuck with this one.

Comment: I could imagine that this is where things start to go south: **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.5.18/src/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php#L282**. If `getRealPath()` fails, you basically end up with `false . '/'`. This needs to be fixed in the core (but you won't get the fix in the 3.5 branch), and I would suggest that you try to log `$path` and details about what it points to (permissions, etc), with the condition of `$path->getRealPath()` returning a `false`-ish result. Maybe it's some kind of race conditions, maybe its a permission problem, maybe something totally different...

Comment: @ndm Thank you very much for your tips. I will try to play with that part of code and will get back to you as soon as I have some output. It can take days since the error happens on random basis and I'm not able to reproduce it myself.

Comment: @ndm So finally the error appeared again. The `getRealPath()` really returns false and therefore there is `/` as a result of that. But it's not a problem of permissions. I would guess that it's cause of higher traffic and 2+ paralel calls of `clear($check)` function. It happens in the `foreach ($contents as $path) {}` so probably if clear() is called more times all of them find the file through iterator, one of the calls deletes the file and other throw the false error. Can you please give me your point of view so I can write the final answer for this thread? Can this be the case? thank you.

Comment: Example paths that returned false:
`/var/www/production/tmp/cache/models/myapp_cake_model_default_admins_permissions`,
`/var/www/production/tmp/cache/models/myapp_cake_model_default_tickets`,
`/var/www/production/tmp/cache/models/myapp_cake_model_default_unread_msgs`. So that is also a reason why I think the problem is not with permissions.

Comment: Sure, as I said, race conditions are certainly a possibility. When one process deleted those files already, but a second process already had them queued before they were deleted, then the `isFile()` check in second process will fail, the code will step to `getRealPath()`, which will also fail, and there you go.

Comment: This [**has been patched**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/15349) in 4.2.4 and 3.9.7

Comment: Nice and fast fix, but what if someone doesn't open_basedir value before this? Root will as after "rm -rf"? Based on file privilieges sure....

Comment: No, the worst that could happen (which still would suck) would be that all files that the webserver user has permission to delete in `/` (which usually should be none) would be deleted, the recursion of the cache clearing process only goes upwards into the cache directory, even with this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @ndm I was able to find the reason of this behavior and a solution. It happens cause of traffic with certain conditions - Multiple requests put the file in delete queue and after the first request deletes the file others fail - `getRealPath()` returns `false` which is then appended with `/` so the result path is `/`.

Worst case scenario if no basedir restriction in place (quoted @ndm):
all files that the webserver user has permission to delete in / (which usually should be none) would be deleted

**Solution 1 (recommended):**
Update your Cake app with patch 3.9.7 or 4.2.4

**Solution 2:**
Manually fix the code to check that `getRealPath()` does not return false